# Logical OR for expected results in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

It will be the best explain in on example

```
expected(someNumber).toBe(1).or.toBe(-2).or.toBe(22) // expect result is 1 or -2 or 22
```

This is bad syntax, but can I do something like that in Jest?

Comment: What do you mean by _"bad syntax"_? Also, why are you expecting three different results?

Comment: This is imaginary syntax -- how it could be, but it isn't :) I wrote it only to show my thoughts

Comment: If this isn't possible with jest, then consider changing your logic. Don't test for three different outputs.

Comment: I would like to writer sth like regression test. One lib give me a result, but I don't know in advance what it will be based on input. Only what I wanna check is that if result is one of options in array

Comment: Can you event unit test a function like that?

Comment: Could you elaborate how you can get this different results in the first place. This sounds really uncommon so maybe the problem is more in your code then in a missing feature in Jest.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly good thing to want.  I have a promise that I want to ensure has resolved, but the test in question doesn't care what it resolved to.  Right now it's undefined, but later it might be changed to something meaningful, and I don't want to have to change my test if that happens.

Comment: This is crazy to me how Jest hasn't implemented this yet. Someone ought to make a formal feature request for it. I have an API that could return 2 different strings, and want to expect the response to be either one of the two, not just one.

Answer (score 34):

A simple way around this is to use the standard `.toContain()` matcher (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tocontainitem) and reverse the expect statement:

```
expect([1, -2, 22]).toContain(someNumber);
```

Answer (score 28):

If you *really* needed to do exactly that, I suppose you could put the logical comparisons inside the `expect` call, e.g.

```
expect(someNumber === 1 || someNumber === -2 || someNumber === 22).toBeTruthy();
```

If this is just for a "quick and dirty" check, this might suffice.

However, as suggested by several comments under your question, there seem to be several "code smells" that make both your initial problem as well as the above solution seem like an inappropriate way of conducting a test.

First, in terms of my proposed solution, that use of `toBeTruthy` is a corruption of the way Jasmine/Jest matchers are meant to be used. It's a bit like using `expect(someNumber === 42).toBeTruthy();` instead of `expect(someNumber).toBe(42)`. The structure of Jest/Jasmine tests is to provide the actual value in the `expect` call (i.e. `expect(actualValue)`) and the expected value in the matcher (e.g. `toBe(expectedValue)` or `toBeTruthy()` where `expectedValue` and `true` are the expected values respectively). In the case above, the actual value is (inappropriately) provided in the `expect` call, with the `toBeTruthy` matcher simply verifying this fact.

It might be that you need to separate your tests. For example, perhaps you have a function (e.g. called `yourFunction`) that you are testing that provides (at least) 3 different possible discrete outputs. I would presume that the value of the output depends on the value of the input. If that is the case, you should probably test all input/output combinations separately, e.g.

```
it('should return 1 for "input A" ', () => {
  const someNumber = yourFunction("input A");
  expect(someNumber).toBe(1);
});

it('should return -2 for "input B" ', () => {
  const someNumber = yourFunction("input B");
  expect(someNumber).toBe(-2);
});

it('should return 22 for "input C" ', () => {
  const someNumber = yourFunction("input C");
  expect(someNumber).toBe(22);
});
```

..or at least...

```
it('should return the appropriate values for the appropriate input ', () => {
  let someNumber;
  someNumber = yourFunction("input A");
  expect(someNumber).toBe(1);

  someNumber = yourFunction("input B");
  expect(someNumber).toBe(-2);

  someNumber = yourFunction("input C");
  expect(someNumber).toBe(22);
});
```

One of the positive consequences of doing this is that, if your code changes in the future such that, e.g. one (but only one) of the conditions changes (in terms of either input *or* output), you only need to update one of three simpler tests instead of the single more complicated aggregate test. Additionally, with the tests separated this way, a failing test will more quickly tell you exactly where the problem is, e.g. with "input A", "input B", or "input C".

Alternatively, you may need to actually refactor `yourFunction`, i.e. the code-under-test itself. Do you really want to have a particular function in your code returning three separate discrete values depending on different input? Perhaps so, but I would examine the code separately to see if it needs to be re-written. It's hard to comment on this further without knowing more details about `yourFunction`.

Comment: To be fair, there are several situations where it's valid for a function under test to return one of several values---e.g. a findShortestPath() in some graph where there are multiple short paths of the same length.

Comment: found this method helpful when feature flagging formatting / masking text

Comment: I just ran into such a situation when my datetime related tests failed because DST started yesterday, and `01:00` just became `+02:00`...

Answer (score 23):

To avoid putting all the logical comparisons in one statement and using toBeTruthy(), you can use nested try/catch statements:

```js
try {
  expect(someNumber).toBe(1)
}
catch{
  try {
    expect(someNumber).toBe(-2)
  }
  catch{
    expect(someNumber).toBe(22)
  }
}
```

To make it more convenient and more readable, you can put this into a helper function:

```js
function expect_or(...tests) {
  if (!tests || !Array.isArray(tests)) return;
  try {
    tests.shift()?.();
  } catch (e) {
    if (tests.length) expect_or(...tests);
    else throw e;
  }
}
```

NB: With Typescript replace line 1 with `function expect_or(...tests: (() => void)[]) {` to add types to the function parameter.

and use it like this:

```js
 expect_or(
   () => expect(someNumber).toBe(1),
   () => expect(someNumber).toBe(-2),
   () => expect(someNumber).toBe(22)
 );
```

Comment: This approach does not seem to work for `.toMatchSnapshot()` assertion in the try..

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It seems that .toMatchSnapshot() does not throw an exception when the match fails - that's why it does not work with my solution. You can change this behavior as described here: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#bail-out, but I would be cautious, as this could clash with the way jest-snapshots work.

Answer (score 8):

As @JrGiant suggested, there could be a `toBeOneOf`, however, it is easy top implement your own matcher:

*Example in TypeScript*:

```
expect.extend({
  toBeOneOf(received: any, items: Array<any>) {
    const pass = items.includes(received);
    const message = () =>
      `expected ${received} to be contained in array [${items}]`;
    if (pass) {
      return {
        message,
        pass: true
      };
    }
    return {
      message,
      pass: false
    };
  }
});

// Declare that jest contains toBeOneOf
// If you are not using TypeScript, remove this "declare global" altogether
declare global {
  namespace jest {
    interface Matchers<R> {
      toBeOneOf(items: Array<any>): CustomMatcherResult;
    }
  }
}

describe("arrays", () => {
  describe("getRandomItemFromArray", () => {
    it("should return one of the expected - 1", () => {
      expect(getRandomItemFromArray([1, 2])).toBeOneOf([1, 2])
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using the `.toContain(item)` matcher. The documentation can be found [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tocontainitem).

The below code should work well:

```js
expect([1, -2, 22]).toContain(someNumber);
```

Comment: + `toContainEqual` if you want deep equality for objects

Answer (score 4):

I was also looking for a solution for the `expect.oneOf` issue. You may want to checkout [d4nyll's solution](https://github.com/d4nyll/jest-matcher-one-of).

Here is an example of how it could work.

```
expect(myfunction()).toBeOneOf([1, -2, 22]);
```